Replace VS Code Snippet Variable
I want to replace ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} with ${TM_DIRECTORY} if ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} is init
I tried this snippet. It works for all files not named init, otherwise the output is -- Name: $TM_DIRECTORY
{
    "filename": {
        "prefix": "filename",
        "body": [
            "${LINE_COMMENT} Name: ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^init$/$TM_DIRECTORY/}"
        ]
    },
}


You can't use a snippet variable in a transform.  So your use of $TM_DIRECTORY will not be resolved to its actual value.  See  Snippet Grammar.
If the file is NOT named init, there is no match in
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^init$/$TM_DIRECTORY/}
and so there is no transform and so ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} is inserted un-transformed.

The closest you are going to get with a pure snippet would be something like:
"filename": {
  "prefix": "filename",
  "body": [
      // "${LINE_COMMENT} Name: ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^init$/$TM_DIRECTORY/}"
      "${LINE_COMMENT} Name: ${1:$TM_FILENAME_BASE}${2:$TM_DIRECTORY}"
  ]
}

Both options, the filenameBase and the directory would appear.  First, the filenameBase would be selected - if you don't want it hit delete and tab past the directory.  If you do want the filenameBase only, tab and delete the now-selected directory.

You can do what you want to do with an extension but it is more complicated.  Let me know if you want to see it.
